# How to call navigationBar(_:shouldPop:) of the parent class in a subclass of UINavigationController?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have written the following code in Objective-C:

```
@interface UINavigationController(UINavigationBar) <UINavigationBarDelegate>

@end

@implementation TestNavigationViewController

- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
    ...
    return [super navigationBar:navigationBar shouldPopItem:item];
}

@end
```

Now I need to implement the swift version of the above code, but I find that I can't do it.

I have tried the following two methods, but neither of them works:

1. Call `super.navigationBar(_:shouldPop:)` directly.
2. `super.perform(#selector(UINavigationBarDelegate.navigationBar(_:shouldPop:)), with: navigationBar, with: item)`

But they don't work:

1. The first method does not pass the compiler, it reports an error.
2. The second method leads to an infinite loop where method `navigationBar(_:shouldPop:)` keeps getting called.

In the end I chose the following method and it works fine in some cases. But in some cases it can cause catastrophic problems. (This is not the point of this question, but I will add it if you are interested)

```swift
extension NavigationViewController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
    
    public func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { return true }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Since the Objective-C code at the beginning doesn't cause any problems, I decided to let the problem go back to the beginning, instead of trying to solve another bug caused by one bug.

How do I implement that Objective-C code in swift?

---

**Supplement1:**

[image]

The `override` keyword was added by auto-completion, but an error was reported...The `?` behind the `navigationBar` is also added by auto-completion.

Comment: `Call super.navigationBar(_:shouldPop:) directly.`I hope you meant 
`return super.navigationBar(navigationBar, shouldPop:item)` But what was your exact code, and what was exactly your error? And if you let autocompletion, the method didn't show?

Comment: @Larme Thank you for your comment, I added the answer to the question.

Comment: It's not `tmpNavigationBar` on the original method. You can't rename the methods and expect to being called.

Comment: @Larme Even if I use the original `navigationBar`, the error reporting doesn't change anything, it still reports these errors...